# Background image appears zoomed in on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am trying to create a simple parallax image with background attachment to fixed. The image looks okay on android's mozilla browser in my android phone and looks okay in chrome developer's tool but when I look at it on my IphoneX, the image looks zoomed in and fixed.
Here is my code.

HTML:

```
  <div class="weddingparallax">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.weddingparallax {
         background-image: url("imageurl");
         background-attachment: fixed;
         background-size: cover;
         background-position: center;
         height: 80vh;
       }
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what it looks like on your iPhone X and what it is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.weddingparallax  {
  background-image: url("imageurl");
  min-height: 500px; /* you can change it */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Do let me know if it works!